# gulp not compiling scss in subfolders

Tags: html, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulpfile

I have the following folder structure:

```html
theme
  assets
    build
      css
        style.css
    src
      theme 
        buttons.scss
      style.scss
  components
    hero
      hero.html
      hero.scss
  index.html
```

Any changes in `src` `theme` and any `scss` file for a component (i.e. `hero.scss`) should all compile into `style.css`.

My `theme` files compile correctly, but my `component` `scss` files don't appear in `style.css`.

Instead, when I run `gulp css`, a separate `css` file appears under the `build` folder, i.e.

```html
build
  css
    style.css
    hero.css
```

How can I get it to compile everything into `style.css`?

`gulpfile.js`

```js
const assetsSRC     = 'assets/src/',
      assetsDST     = 'assets/build/',
      components    = 'components/';

const gulp          = require('gulp'),
      sass          = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
      sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
      fs            = require('fs'),
      path          = require('path'),
      merge         = require('merge-stream'),
      postcss       = require('gulp-postcss'),
      autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      plumber       = require('gulp-plumber'),
      concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
      strip         = require('gulp-strip-comments');

const componentCSS    = components + '**/*.scss',
      componentJS     = components + '**/*.js',
      globalCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/style.scss';
      configCSS       = assetsSRC + 'scss/config/**.scss';
      themeCSS        = assetsSRC + 'scss/theme/**.scss';
      globalJS        = assetsSRC + 'js/*.js';
      libJS           = assetsSRC + 'js/lib/*.js';

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
};

function getFolders(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}


function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css');
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '/**/*.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}


function mainCSS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
  return gulp.src(globalCSS, { allowEmpty: true })
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function libraryJS() {
  var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'JS/lib');
  return gulp.src(libJS).pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
}


function watch() {
  gulp.watch([globalCSS,configCSS,themeCSS, componentCSS],mainCSS);
}


exports.mainCSS = mainCSS;
exports.mainJS = mainJS;
exports.libraryJS = libraryJS;
exports.css = css;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.watch = watch;

const build = gulp.series(watch);
gulp.task('default', build);
```

#### Edit

Attempt using `gulp-sass-glob`:

```js
function css() {
  gulp.task('styles', function () {
    var src = path(components);
    return gulp
      .src(src, '/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sassGlob())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(assetsDST + 'css'));
  });
}
```

Re-ran `gulp watch` (no errors). Made a change and saved `hero.scss`. Then went into `style.css` to find `css` that has been compiled from `hero.scss` - nothing shows. `scss` not compiled into `style.css`

#### Edit 2

I have the following:

```js
function css() {
  var folders = getFolders(components);
  var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
    var src = path.join(components, folder);
    var dst = path.join(assetsDST + 'css/');
    return gulp.src(path.join(src, '**/*.scss'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
  });
  return merge(tasks);
}
```

This is creating individual `css` files (rather than collating into `style.css`). I think this one is close, but unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gulp-sass-glob?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob

Comment: I've just tried it, no luck - have updated question to showcase demo.

Comment: What's in your src variable? This should contain the SASS source according to the docs https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src/

Comment: My bad, forgot to add in the `src`, but it's essentially just the `components` folder (`var src = path(components);`) - Have updated my edit to add in the snippet

Comment: SRC should just be your main SASS file path, from there you import your components via SASS

Comment: You're saying to import `hero.scss` into `stye.scss`? If so, I'm looking to keep the `scss` files under the `component` folder, in order to keep things manageable. Let me know if I'm misinterpreting